# Failed to initialize connector

Tags: java, server, http2, server.xml, tomcat8.5

SEVERE: Failed to initialize component [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol-8443]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: The configured protocol [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol] requires the APR/native library which is not available.

[image: below is the eclipse neon server output window] 
I have commented the connector for `http` and opened the connector for `http2`.

here is the code :

```
 <Connector port="9000" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
                   maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" >
            <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
            <SSLHostConfig>
                <Certificate certificateKeyFile="conf/localhost-rsa-key.pem"
                             certificateFile="conf/localhost-rsa-cert.pem"                         
                             type="RSA" />
            </SSLHostConfig>
        </Connector>
```

I am getting an error while starting the server.

Comment: The problem is that Tomcat cannot load the APR native library.  You need to install it, either from your (Linux) distro's package system, by downloading a binary, or downloading and building the source bundle.